# Error javascript define magento2 : window.checkout.quoteData or store code are undefined

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I cannot inject some javascript dependencies of magento in my main.js.

ex:
'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined   at quote.js:13

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'storeCode' of undefined  at url-builder.js:12

I see problem with window.checkoutConfig

Do you have an idea to fix that ?

```
define([
    "jquery",
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
],
function ($, getPaymentInformationAction, totals) {});
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? If yes, could you please provide the fix?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that both file don't have the correct information when the page is loaded, as this information is only available on the checkout page.

When i added in a JS file with your same code onto any page on the site, i get the same errors. When i add that same file into a template loaded on the checkout page, the errors goes away and i'm able to output the contents of both the `getPaymentInformationAction` and `totals` into the console.

```
define([
        "jquery",
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
    ],
    function ($, getPaymentInformationAction, totals) {
        console.log(getPaymentInformationAction);
        console.log(totals);
    });
```

[image]

Without a clear understanding of how and where you are trying to use this file, i can't say for sure how to implement these files correctly.

Comment: Thanks, so, how add add  javascript file with "define" only on the checkout page ?

Comment: (I merged the file javascript when  production is enabled)

Comment: It depends on how you are trying to do this. Are you creating a theme or a module? For testing i just put a `<script type="text/x-magento-init">` in the `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml` file override. That is only called on checkout, so it works that way. But unfortunately there are so many ways to do this depending on what your end goal is. Let me know and i'm sure we can figure out a solution.

Comment: I want call my function javascript only on checkout, so i think your solution is the best ? 

Thanks a lot.