# Getting window.checkout.quoteData or store code are undefined error when cart item count updated using ajax

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have created a custom page with free text ordering functionality and called custom `add to cart API` to add items to the cart.

Once the item is added I need to update the cart item count with updated quantity. I tried to use

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals'
], function ($, getTotalsAction) {
    'use strict';

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    getTotalsAction([], deferred);
});
```

But It is throwing error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined at quote.js:34

And

url-builder.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'storeCode' of undefined at url-builder.js:12

Anything missing here?

I referred [Error javascript define magento2 : window.checkout.quoteData or store code are undefined](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210517/error-javascript-define-magento2-window-checkout-quotedata-or-store-code-are-u) which doesn't have any working solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this my the below code. It might help someone

```
require([
       'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    ], function (customerData) {
        var sections = ['cart'];
        customerData.invalidate(sections);
        customerData.reload(sections, true);
    });
```